# Set TinyMCE editor option after Initialization

Tags: javascript, initialization, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

How to set [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/) `templates` option after initialization? Is it possible in TinyMCE 4?

I've seen in a source code of [Template plugin](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/template/) that this option is read every time user clicks on 'Insert template' button. So I think it could pick up a new value on every click.

**ps.** A possible solution could be to use URL in `templates`, but let's pretend it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** In TinyMCE v4.3.3 Templates plugin was updated, so `templates` setting can be a function that gets a callback that can provide templates. Good news, you don't have to patch plugin =)

Initialization:

```
$scope.tinyMceOptions = {
    plugins: 'template',
    ...
    templates: function(callback) {
        // Here you can do whatever you want with callback;
        // for example, you can provide different arguments on every click
        callback($scope.variableTemplates);
    }
```

---

*(For previous TinyMCE versions)* My solution is to patch Template plugin that I can specify a function as templates provider. Here's what I've added to `createTemplateList()` function:

```
else if (typeof templateList === 'function') {
    callback(templateList());
}
```

And during initialization I specify a function in `templates`:

```
$scope.tinyMceOptions = {
    plugins: 'template',
    ...
    templates: function() {
        return $scope.variableTemplates;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried doing this a few days ago - specifically to load the items in a submenu when the submenu button was clicked. It sounds like this is the same problem.

I could not find a way to do this, apart from to destroy the editor instance and call tinymce.init() again with the modified configuration.